# FIND_IN_SET not finding values at the edges of the haystack

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column called `category`, one row (which I'm trying to find) has a value in that column of `'17,1,3'`. I'm running the following few queries with the outlined results:

```
SELECT * FROM firms WHERE FIND_IN_SET(17, category) > 0;
```

0 results

```
SELECT * FROM firms WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, category) > 0;
```

1 result

```
SELECT * FROM firms WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, category) > 0;
```

0 results

Why is it not returning any results when the value I'm searching for is at the edge of the list? This is repeatable with longer lists as well, if I have 5 numbers it works fine with the middle 3, but not the outer 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint:  Don't store lists as comma-delimited strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff as I understand it it's a requirement for FIND_IN_SET?

Comment: you should use normalized data and not comma separated values like you currently do. So you can use other mysql feature for your query instead of FIND_IN_SET. What is exactly your goal?

Comment: @LelioFaieta The table has a list of companies, each company can be in one or more categories, I want to be able to query all companies in a given category.

Comment: Three tables: companies, categories and the third is where you store a record for each couple of company category. Each company is repeated as many times as categories it is in. This is the correct database design for this goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use single quotes around the needle substring to look for in the haystick.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM firms WHERE FIND_IN_SET('17', category) > 0;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM firms WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', category) > 0;
```

Also, **note that** you have Slashes at the end and beginning of `category` string, which are interfering. You need to get rid of those slashes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both methods and neither works as expected, the query still doesn't find the row in these two cases.

Comment: @czarsimon please add sample data to your question reproducing the case. I have a doubt that `category` field does not have the values as you specify

Comment: Please see this pastebin for sample data: https://pastebin.com/Gh4ci1ZZ

Comment: @czarsimon ok understood. Slashes at the end and beginning are interferring. You need to get rid of those slashes

Comment: Oh lord, I was reading the documentation and got hung up on the data format and used the quotations unnecessarily. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use like it will return all three cases

```
 select * from firms where category like '%17%'
 select * from firms where category like '%3%'
 select * from firms where category like '%1%'
```